# Programming patterns - example study

Tags: java, design-patterns

I had this question on my test:

> What kind of programming / design pattern is this:
>
> ```
> FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
> BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);
> ```

I'm sorry for the trouble, but definitions of programming patterns are unclear for me and I don't know how to answer this question correctly.

Comment: I believe they're looking for the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's an example of the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

As the linked Wikipedia article states:

> Decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behaviour to be added to an existing object dynamically.

In your example, you're adding buffering to a `FileReader`, which provides more efficient reading than a regular, un-buffered `FileReader`.

Answer (score 1):

This is `Decorator` pattern. From *Design Patterns* book:

> Intent: attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically.
>   Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending
>   functionality
>
> ...
>
> Applicability: Use Decorator
>
> - to add responsibilities to individual objects dynamically and transparently, that is, without affecting other objects.
> - for responsibilities that can be withdrawn.
> - when extension by subclassing is impractical. Sometimes a large number of independent extensions are possible and would produce an
>     explosion of subclasses to support every combination. Or a class
>     definition may be hidden or otherwise unavailable for subclassing.

In case of `BufferedReader`, it attaches buffering feature to `FileReader`.

If you want to know more about patterns, I recommend reading this book (or more lighter "Head First Patterns"). **Additionally**, there's brilliant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns) on SO about patterns usage inside JDK -- very cool stuff!